# Lower expression in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, mtpro

I am using the `mtpro2` math font and I want to lower the expression inside the big parenthesis in the following equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\[ y(x)=c_1y_1(x)\XL\int{\PARENS{\left( \frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'(x)\XL\int{\frac{1}{\left[\left( \frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'(x)\right]^2\cdot y_1^3(x)\cdot e^{\frac{a_2}{a_3}x} }dx}} dx}+c_2y_2(x)+c_3y_1(x)\ ,\ x\in I \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]
I tryied to use `\raisebox` but it didn't work

Comment: `\PARENS` will center its contents with respect to the math axis, so the same problem appears whenever the contents is a fraction with different heights in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: You can add `\vphantom{\left[\left( \frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'(x)\right]^2\cdot y_1^3(x)\cdot e^{\frac{a_2}{a_3}x}}` to the first argument of `\frac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `\PARENS{<subformula>}` does (apart from a different choice of parentheses) is

```
\left(
\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle <subformula>$}}
\right)
```

This means that the output of something as easy as

```
\[
\frac{a}{b}\PARENS{\frac{a}{\dbinom{b}{c}}}
\]
```

is the completely wrong

[image]

Of course nobody would want to write that subformula, but it's a good example of what happens.

You get a better output with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
y(x)=c_1y_1(x)\XL\int
\Biggl(
  \left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)^{\!\prime}(x)
  \XL\int\frac{1}{\Bigl[\left( \frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'(x)\Bigr]^2}
  \cdot y_1^3(x)\cdot e^{\frac{a_2}{a_3}x}\,dx
\Biggr) \,dx+c_2y_2(x)+c_3y_1(x)\ ,\ x\in I
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, build the big parentheses separately:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
y(x)=c_1y_1(x)\XL\int
\LEFTRIGHT(.{\vphantom{\XL\int}}\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace
  \left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)^{\!\prime}(x)
  \XL\int\frac{1}{\Bigl[\left( \frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'(x)\Bigr]^2}
  \cdot y_1^3(x)\cdot e^{\frac{a_2}{a_3}x}\,dx
\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace\LEFTRIGHT.){\vphantom{\XL\int}}
\,dx+c_2y_2(x)+c_3y_1(x)\ ,\ x\in I
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]